# time:go creates NullPointerException error in NetLogo

Tags: time, netlogo

I am trying to make use of the time extension of NetLogo, but unfortunately it throws a NullPointerException error at me, when using the time:go function.

My code:

```
extensions [
  time
]

to setup
  ca
  create-turtles 5
  time:schedule-event turtles (task fd) 10
  time:schedule-event (turtle 1) (task fd) 5
  time:go
end
```

The error that appears both in NetLogo 5.0.4 and 5.2:

```
error (NullPointerException)
 while observer running TIME:GO
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'

NetLogo is unable to supply you with more details about this error.  Please report the problem
at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues, or to bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu, and paste the
contents of this window into your report.

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at TimeExtension$LogoSchedule.performScheduledTasks(TimeExtension.java:593)
 at TimeExtension$LogoSchedule.performScheduledTasks(TimeExtension.java:578)
 at TimeExtension$Go.perform(TimeExtension.java:1655)
 at org.nlogo.prim._extern.perform(_extern.java:54)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:91)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.java:82)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.org$nlogo$job$JobThread$$runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:143)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobThread.scala:78)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76)
 at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)
 at org.nlogo.util.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:75)

NetLogo 5.0.4
main: org.nlogo.app.AppFrame
thread: JobThread
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_65 (Apple Inc.; 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
operating system: Mac OS X 10.10.5 (x86_64 processor)
Scala version 2.9.2
JOGL: (3D View not initialized)
OpenGL Graphics: (3D View not initialized)
model: DES test 5.0.4

04:14:41.545 SwitchedTabsEvent (org.nlogo.app.Tabs) AWT-EventQueue-0
04:14:41.542 RuntimeErrorEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
04:14:41.542 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
04:14:41.542 AddJobEvent (org.nlogo.window.ButtonWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
04:14:41.399 InputBoxLoseFocusEvent (org.nlogo.window.ButtonWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
04:14:41.374 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
04:14:41.174 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
04:14:40.973 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
04:14:40.745 JobRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread
04:14:40.701 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
```

Comment: also reported at https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/issues/43

Comment: Does it crash when you don't use this extension? As far as I know, NetLogo uses an obsolete version of JOGL, it doesn't help to make it work and you see "JOGL: (3D View not initialized)".